# How to connect internet via esp32 ap mode

Tags: c, esp32

everyone.

I have a problem now...

I want to make a something as like ESP32 AP + STA Mode

my client is iPAD and iPAD(STA) connect to ESP32(AP + STA Mode)

also my ESP32(STA) Connected to my Router.

according to serial log of arduino my esp32 got a ip.

exactly two ip . AP ip and STA ip.

I sent a ping by icmp from router.

ipTime router sent a ping to esp32(STA) successfuly.

sorry for my stupid english.. anyway.

i want to make a like this.

iPAD <-> ESP32(AP+STA) <-> Router (internet)

ESP32 is working AP and STA both mode.

iPAD is station of ESP32 and i want to using internet via ESP32

iPAD -> ESP32 -> Router(Internet)

anyone give me solution?

below is my code.

```
#include <WiFi.h>

#define LOG                                 Serial

#define AP_SSID                             "ESP32_AP_STA"
#define AP_PASS                             "123456789a"

#define STA_SSID                            "jeong"
#define STA_PASS                            "jong1992"

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 50);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

WiFiServer TCPServer(1234, ip);
WiFiClient TCPClient;

void setup(void)
{
    LOG.begin(115200);

    while(!LOG)
    {
        ;
    }

    WiFi.disconnect(true);
    // WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
    WiFi.softAPConfig(ip, gateway, subnet);
    WiFi.softAP(AP_SSID, AP_PASS);
    delay(100);

    TCPServer.begin();
    TCPServer.setNoDelay(true);

    WiFi.begin(STA_SSID, STA_PASS);
    WiFi.setHostname(AP_SSID);
    
    while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
    {
        delay(200);
        LOG.print("+");
    }

    LOG.print(STA_SSID);
    LOG.print(" : ");
    LOG.println(WiFi.localIP());

    LOG.print(AP_SSID);
    LOG.print(" : ");
    LOG.println(WiFi.softAPIP());
}

void loop(void)
{
    
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please don't add your codes as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a router with NAT functionality. Since this is non-trivial, I'll just refer you to the first project that popped up when searching for "esp32 nat router": https://github.com/martin-ger/esp32_nat_router

Comment: You can use ESp32 in AP and STA mode